# how to implement this 2d vector to my code

Tags: c++, vector

the code i'm working on takes a matrix of different dimensions every input so i need to be dynamic and i need to make it with a vector but it gets me tons of errors each time i try

```cpp
const int n=6;   const int m=3;
float matrix1 [n][m];
float matrix2 [n][m];
float matrixsum [n][m];
```

how to make this into a vector instead of a 2d array
here is the full code that takes the string then cut it and then takes the numbers in it and make it into an array so you can see the big picture https://ideone.com/4MwJVF
it takes an input like this

```
[1 -2.5 3;4 5.25 6;7 8 9.12]
+
[3 4.2 10.2;12 -1 0;67 2 13]
```

and an output like this

```
[4 1.7 13.2;16 4.25 6;74 10 22.12]
```

Comment: Cannot give a good answer unless you let us know what is going wrong with what you tried. Please add code from what you attempted. [mcve] is recommended.

Comment: @user4581301 well.. i linked the complete code i've tried

Comment: Links rot and get blocked by firewalls. Don't use them for anything important to understanding and answering the question.

Comment: the problem is that i need the 2d array to be up to 100*100 so i'm going to need to use vectors for such a thing but it doesn't seem to work properly in my code

Comment: Looked at the link. It shows nothing of how you are using `vector`s.

Comment: its a big code like 170 lines or something i can't post it here

Comment: Start with a few simple experiments to get a feel for how to use `vector`s, then try to apply vectors to your code.

Comment: thats the one where i used vectors https://ideone.com/QJohqt

Comment: Pass the `vector`s by reference or they get copied, you change the copy, and your work is lost. Eg; `void splitter(string x,vector<vector<float> > & matrix)`. Unrelated, consider passing the `string` by reference as well, but since you don't intend to change the `string` make it `const`. `void splitter(const string & x,vector<vector<float> >matrix)`

Comment: Near duplicate: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: i don't think that's the case the code runs just fine if it was a static 2d array
the thing is i need it to be 2d but dynamic because the input is dimensions might vary

Comment: [Arrays decay to pointers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) They are ALWAYS passed by reference. Everything else follows different rules and you have to ask for pass by reference. This is because back in early days of C you didn't have the processor power or the memory to pass an array by value. 50 years later things are different, but because billions of lines of code would be ruined if the behaviour was changed, the behaviour is not being changed.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic-sized matrix would look something like this

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> matrix;

matrix.push_back(...) // push a row vector
matrix[0].push_back(...) // push an element
```

Comment: Prefer `std::vector<std::vector<float>> matrix(n, std::vector<float>(m));` Easier set up and more array-like in usage.

Comment: @user4581301 ya I forgot about that constructor